# Excel - how can I count rows based on three column values?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following columns:

```
bonus1  bonus2  bonus3
  1       2       3
  4       1       2
  3       4       0
  0       0       0
```

I want to count each row once if the any of the columns is greater than 0, and count only once.
So the result for the above data should be 3
(because the first three rows contain positive numbers, but the fourth row doesn't).

I want to use a formula without creating another column.  The column will be lost once the sheet is refreshed.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a formula/script writing service. We are here to help you, not do it for you. This means we need to know what you've tried so we can assist where you got stuck. For additional clarification, when you say *"I want to use a formula without creating another column"*, where do you expect the formula to go?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array formula:

```
=SUM(IF(Table1[bonus1]+Table1[bonus2]+Table1[bonus3] > 0, 1))
```

entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.